Getting error for mapbox maps package that has been installed
I am learning swift and the Mapbox Navigation SDK and I can't get the code to compile due to a Cannot find 'ResourceOptions' in scope. I have checked the instillation several times as well as checked for dependancies. I am a novice with swift so I am hoping the issue is ignorance and any help debugging this will give you great karma. ;-)
Screen shot of package dependancies
Screen shot of package dependancies
Code
import UIKit
import MapboxMaps

/// A view controller for managing annotations on the Mapbox map.
class AnnotationsMapViewController: UIViewController {
    /// The Mapbox map view.
    var mapView: MapView!
    
    /// The view model managing the annotations on the map.
    var viewModel: AnnotationsMapViewModel?
    
    /// Called after the controller's view is loaded into memory.
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Use the provided access token directly
        let accessToken = "Put Access Token Here"
        
        // Configure the resource options with the access token
        let resourceOptions = ResourceOptions(accessToken: accessToken)
        
        // Initialize the map options with the resource options and desired style
        let mapInitOptions = MapInitOptions(resourceOptions: resourceOptions, styleURI: .streets)
        
        // Correct usage of MapView initializer to create the map view
        mapView = MapView(frame: view.bounds, mapInitOptions: mapInitOptions)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        
        // Ensure annotation managers are set when the map style loads
        mapView.mapboxMap.onNext(event: .styleLoaded) { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.setupAnnotationManagers()
            self.updateAnnotations()
            self.setupGestureRecognizers()
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Setup Annotation Managers
    /**
     Sets up the annotation managers for managing point and polyline annotations.
     
     This method initializes the point and polyline annotation managers if they are not already initialized.
     It prints debug information to the console to confirm the initialization status of the annotation managers.
     */
    private func setupAnnotationManagers() {
        guard let mapView = mapView else { return }
        
        if viewModel?.pointAnnotationManager == nil {
            viewModel?.pointAnnotationManager = mapView.annotations.makePointAnnotationManager()
            print("***** PointAnnotationManager initialized: \(viewModel?.pointAnnotationManager != nil)")
        }
        
        if viewModel?.polylineAnnotationManager == nil {
            viewModel?.polylineAnnotationManager = mapView.annotations.makePolylineAnnotationManager()
            print("***** PolylineAnnotationManager initialized: \(viewModel?.polylineAnnotationManager != nil)")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Update Annotations
    /**
     Updates the annotations on the map by setting the annotations for the point annotation manager.
     
     This method fetches the annotations from the view model and sets them on the point annotation manager.
     It also ensures that polylines are updated by calling the view model's `updatePolylines` method.
     */
    func updateAnnotations() {
        guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }
        
        viewModel.pointAnnotationManager?.annotations = viewModel.annotations
        viewModel.updatePolylines() // Ensure this is called to apply the updates
    }
    
    // MARK: - Setup Gesture Recognizers
    /**
     Sets up the gesture recognizers for handling annotation selection.
     
     This method adds a tap gesture recognizer to the map view. The gesture recognizer calls the `handleAnnotationTap` method
     when a tap is detected on the map view.
     */
    private func setupGestureRecognizers() {
        guard let mapView = mapView else { return }
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleAnnotationTap(_:)))
        mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Handle Annotation Tap
    /**
     Handles the tap gesture on annotations.
     
     This method queries the rendered features at the tap location to identify and select the tapped annotation or polyline.
     If a matching annotation or polyline is found, it is selected; otherwise, any selected polyline is deselected.
     
     - Parameter sender: The tap gesture recognizer.
     */
    @objc private func handleAnnotationTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let mapView = mapView, let viewModel = viewModel else { return }
        let point = sender.location(in: mapView)
        
        // Adjust the buffer size for hit-testing
        let buffer: CGFloat = 1.0 // Buffer size in screen points
        let hitbox = CGRect(x: point.x - buffer, y: point.y - buffer, width: 2 * buffer, height: 2 * buffer) // Use the hitbox directly
        
        // Query the rendered features within the hitbox
        let options = RenderedQueryOptions(layerIds: ["annotations-layer"], filter: nil)
        mapView.mapboxMap.queryRenderedFeatures(in: hitbox, options: options) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let features):
                print("***** Number of features detected: \(features.count)")
                for feature in features {
                    if let userInfo = feature.feature.properties?["userInfo"] as? Turf.JSONValue,
                       case let .object(annotationInfo) = userInfo,
                       let annotationIdValue = annotationInfo["annotation-id"],
                       case let .string(annotationId) = annotationIdValue {
                        if let selectedAnnotation = viewModel.annotations.first(where: { ($0.userInfo?["annotation-id"] as? String) == annotationId }) {
                            viewModel.selectAnnotation(selectedAnnotation)
                            print("***** Selected annotation with ID: \(annotationId)")
                            return
                        }
                        if let selectedPolyline = viewModel.polylines.first(where: { ($0.userInfo?["annotation-id"] as? String) == annotationId }) {
                            viewModel.selectPolyline(selectedPolyline)
                            print("***** Selected polyline with ID: \(annotationId)")
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Deselect if no matching annotation found
                viewModel.deselectPolyline()
                print("***** No matching annotation found, deselecting polyline")
            case .failure(let error):
                viewModel.deselectPolyline()
                print("***** Failed to query rendered features: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Query Rendered Features
    /**
     Handles querying of rendered features.
     
     This method queries the rendered features at the specified point and calls the completion handler with the result.
     
     - Parameters:
       - point: The point at which to query rendered features.
       - options: The options for the query.
       - completion: The completion handler to call with the query results.
     */
    private func queryRenderedFeatures(at point: CGPoint, options: RenderedQueryOptions, completion: @escaping (Result<[QueriedRenderedFeature], Error>) -> Void) {
        mapView.mapboxMap.queryRenderedFeatures(with: point, options: options, completion: completion)
    }
}

see above

I don't know which tutorial you're seeing but you might want to look at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-ios/blob/02a875663498696f9ba2917956197cc583c9e9b4/CHANGELOG.md#1100-alpha2---21-june-2023 where it states that there has been a changed about that: Remove ResourceOptions and ResourceOptionsManager. Introduce MapboxOptions and MapboxMapsOptions to handle application-level access token and other generic options.

Either downgrade the version or look for an updated tutorial.

Provide screenshot of the error or provide error's text.
